# Передавать в .format список переменных

Tags: python, format

Допустим у меня есть строка

```
reminder_text = 'Не забудь прислать отчет за %s по проекту %s, пожалуйста.'
```

Сейчас ей передаются аргументы `% (date, project.name)`, где `project.name` - строка. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы вместо `project.name` передавался список названий проектов, то есть `project_names = [project1.name, project2.name, project3.name]` и конечный вывод строки был:

> ```
> 'Не забудь прислать отчет за %s по проектам project1.name, project2.name, project3.name, пожалуйста.'
> ```

Как мне этого добиться?

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте:

```
text = 'Не забудь прислать отчет за %s по проектам %s, пожалуйста.' % (date, ', '.join(x.name for x in project_names))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [5]: project_names = ['project1.name', 'project2.name', 'project3.name']

In [6]: reminder_text = 'Не забудь прислать отчет за {} по проекту {}, пожалуйста.'

In [7]: reminder_text.format('8.24.2018', ', '.join(project_names))
Out[7]: 'Не забудь прислать отчет за 8.24.2018 по проекту project1.name, project2.name, project3.name, пожалуйста.'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my_format = {"date": "24.08.2018", "project_names": ", ".join([u"№1", u"№2", u"№3"])}
print 'Не забудь прислать отчет за {date} по проектам {project_names}, пожалуйста.'.format(**my_format)
# Не забудь прислать отчет за 24.08.2018 по проектам №1, №2, №3, пожалуйста.
```

Comment: По моему я дал аналогичный ответ

Comment: быстро печатаешь видать

Comment: подправил чтобы "по другому"